# Caching on Django Rest Framework GenericViews

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views, django-cache

I don`t find infos on how caching of Django Rest Framework generic views is configured. Do I have to override the get message and add an own @method_decorator? This feels ungeneric to me.

```
class BlogTags(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = CustomContentBlogTag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomContentBlogTagSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    @method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 60 * 24))
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Docs I found:
Caching: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/
Generic views: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

In the generic views docs, there is a sentence, that the queryset is cached somehow. But what, if I want the whole view to be cached?

Comment: That's correct and I don't get what's "ungeneric".

Comment: I have to override a function without changes, only to add a decorator. But maybe it`s just fine like that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `name` parameter on `method_decorator` and decorate a class. In fact when you use it on a class, the `name` is required.

Example:

```py
@method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 5), name="list")
class MyView(mixins.ListModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    ...
```